# EclipseLink password with § symbol

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem concerning my database connection with EclipseLink. When I use a password that contains the § symbol I get an SQLException. Without EclipseLink there is no problem.

I tried other special character without EclipseLink: § and $ are the only legal special characters. Passwords containing a $ symbol work with EclipseLink as well while passwords containing a § symbol don't.

My guess would be that EclipseLink replaces the § with a code which leads to the error below. Has someone allready dealt with this? Is there a way to fix it?

Exception:

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: The application server rejected the connection. (The user ID or password contains a character that is not valid.)
Error Code: -99999

database: AS400 iSeries

JPA provider: EclipseLink 2.4.1

Persistence XML:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="unit1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/bvlistenermapping.xml</mapping-file>

    <class>...</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database"
            value="de.meyerwerft.common.db.helper.DB2UDBiSeriesPlatform" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:as400://###;prompt=false;naming=sql;errors=full;date format=eur;time format=eur;decimal separator=.;blocksize=512;translate binary=true;" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger"
            value="###" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Thanks in advance for any useful hints.

Greetz Malte

Comment: I'm a little confused with the sentences involving what works and what doesn't, as they are kind of contradictory.  Here's what I'm reading: With EclipseLink, `§` and `$` are treated as illegal characters.  Without EclipseLink, none are treated as illegal characters.  Is this correct?

Comment: With EclipseLink the $ is treated as legal and the § as illegal character. Without EclipseLink both are legal.

Comment: This likely has to do with encryption/decryption of the password not handling the special character: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/Security

Comment: Thanks @Chris. The problem has really to do with the encryption/decryption. It turned out this is no EclipseLink bug as I thought, but an bug somewhere in my code where the password already was encrypted/decrypted.

Comment: Here Like your problem with `§` character http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607230/inserting-special-characters-in-database-with-ibm-data-db2-iseries-provider

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. The problem really has to do with the encryption/decryption of the password. But it is not an EclipseLink problem as I thought first.
The password was already encrypted and decrypted bevore it was given to EclipseLink. So the error is located somewhere in my code. It turned out that the decryption replaced the '§' symbol with an '?' symbol which is not allowed.